# Why won't my rig show up?

Tags: rendering

I tried animating with my Minecraft rig, and for the first few hours it was working and it even shows in the rendered view, but when I did put it on render view, the rig can't be seen. I don't know why it happens like that.

This is on the material viewport: [image]

But when I put it on rendered:[image]

Why does this happen? The rig isn't restricted to render too, so I'm very confused. Here is the file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/og2zy0v2fd072q8/running_steve.blend

Comment: too many things to be looked at in order to trouble shoot. Can you upload your blend file?

Comment: @SVAFnemesis I put the link in now.

Comment: Hello?? I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it, you said it isn't render restricted, It IS. Your rig has a visibility driver system that turns its visibility on and off. I don't know where the controls are, I only know it because I see a lot of drivers going in and out of its restriction settings. I would just delete them if I were you. But if you wish to make use of this function, I think it's best to contact the author for manual.

Comment: actually I fixed the problem by putting the animation data to another character, since by the time I did that I knew something was wrong. :) Thanks for tip btw.